# Sequelize - How do I fix "DataTypes is not defined"?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to have a model in sequelize generate a unique ID using `DataTypes.UUID`. This throws an error when I serve up my application

`ReferenceError: DataTypes is not defined`

**Here's my code**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('uppersphere', '****', '***', {
  logging: false
});
...
var Peak = sequelize.define('peak', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
    primaryKey: true
  },
```

**Here's the documentation**

```
sequelize.define('model', {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  })
```

The obvious answer is that it's not my code, but there's some `require()` that I need. However, I don't see any documentation on what to require to get DataTypes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Data Types can be accessed via the [`Sequelize` object](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#data-types):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var Peak = sequelize.define('peak', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
    primaryKey: true
  },
```

`DataTypes` is a just a [convenience class](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/) which you can import directly if needed:

```
var DataTypes = require('sequelize/lib/data-types');
```

---

Also, [the model files are imported](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#import) with `DataTypes` as a second argument

Comment: I already have that in my code. It is implied with the `...` But thank you for trying. It looks like stackoverflow kinda formatted it weird, so that may not have been noticeable. I'll actually go ahead and make it more clear to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @DanielBreen updated the answer with some more details. Hope that at least set you on the correct path. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @alecxe. That was the missing link!